# A stack overflow exception occurred when I tried to create a sparkSession using spark (version 3.1.1)

Tags: scala, apache-spark

When I try to create a sparkSession using spark-shell, a stack overflow error occurs. I traced the stack overflow to a problem with scala-reflect-2.12.10.jar  path handling and triggered by spark when creating the sessionState, but I can't get any more details.

What specific actions trigger this problem when spark creates a sparSession and how should I avoid this problem。

exec envs：
spark 3.1.1
[image]

exec command:

```
scala
val spark =  org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.builder().appName("test")
spark.getOrCreate()
```

errors:

```scala
scala> val spark =  org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.builder().appName("test")
spark: org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.Builder = org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder@3dcb28de

scala> spark.getOrCreate()
Start create spark session
23/08/21 12:08:20 ERROR SparkSession$Builder: Start create spark session
23/08/21 12:08:20 ERROR SparkSession$Builder: Get spark session from active
Start get spark session state
Start get sparksession className:org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionStateBuilder
23/08/21 12:08:20 ERROR SparkSession: Successfully get class
23/08/21 12:08:20 ERROR SparkSession: Successfully get costructor
23/08/21 12:08:20 ERROR SparkSession: Successfully get new Instance
23/08/21 12:08:20 ERROR SparkSession: Successfully type convert to BaseSessionStateBuilder
Start create new Session state
2023-08-21 12:08:30,734 main DEBUG null null initializing configuration org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfiguration@4acbe932
2023-08-21 12:08:30,789 main DEBUG Installed 2 script engines
Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
2023-08-21 12:08:31,851 Thread Context Data Task DEBUG Thread Context Data Service Provider initialization complete
2023-08-21 12:08:32,088 main DEBUG Oracle Nashorn version: 11.0.16, language: ECMAScript, threading: Not Thread Safe, compile: true, names: [nashorn, Nashorn, js, JS, JavaScript, javascript, ECMAScript, ecmascript], factory class: jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngineFactory
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive$.splitPath(ZipArchive.scala:62)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive$.scala$reflect$io$ZipArchive$$dirName(ZipArchive.scala:58)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
        at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.io.ZipArchive.ensureDir(ZipArchive.scala:114)
```

This logs can be ignored

```scala
23/08/21 12:08:20 ERROR SparkSession$Builder: Start create spark session
23/08/21 12:08:20 ERROR SparkSession$Builder: Get spark session from active
Start get spark session state
Start get sparksession className:org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionStateBuilder
23/08/21 12:08:20 ERROR SparkSession: Successfully get class
23/08/21 12:08:20 ERROR SparkSession: Successfully get costructor
23/08/21 12:08:20 ERROR SparkSession: Successfully get new Instance
23/08/21 12:08:20 ERROR SparkSession: Successfully type convert to BaseSessionStateBuilder
Start create new Session state
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code or errors, copy it in plain text in your post.

Answer (score 0):

`spark-shell` creates Spark Session automatically with the name '`spark`'. You can not create or override the existing session i.e. `spark`.

if you will check the **spark-shell** screen print that you had shared, just above the Spark logo, there is a line already mentioned

***Spark Session is available as 'spark'***.

If you have any use case where you need to pass certain configuration then you can pass that as a part of `spark-shell` command like below

```
spark-shell --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="-Duser.timezone=GMT+5:30"
```

Comment: The above code operation maybe awkward, but it is the easiest way to reproduce the problem.According to the documentation(https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate.html pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate gets an existing SparkSession or, if there is no existing one, creates a new one based on the options set in this builder.), the above reasons are obviously not enough to cause the problem